# How can I debug a hanging ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, connection, osx-snow-leopard

I have two virtual servers with the same host provider. After regenerating my SSH keys on my client machine (local) I con only connect to one of the virtual servers. When I connect to the other (both are being done via the terminal) it just hangs. It's not timing out and I see nothing in the SSH logs that indicates a connection error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to launch ssh -v or even ssh -vv instead of just ssh.